# Capital One Free Credit Report - Effect on Credit Score

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, online-banking, online-tools

I have a Capital One credit card.  As part of their online services, they offer free credit score requests.  I recently began using that service, up to twice or thrice per month.

Capital One mentioned that I may see "Soft Inquiry"s in my credit report as a result.  Will those (or any other aspect of the service) have an effect on my credit score?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two types of inquiries: the hard pull, indicating a new account has been applied for, and the soft pull, which is either a consumer reviewing his own info or a bank running scans to find potential new customers.  The soft pulls do not affect your FICO score.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE.